# How to build a Rubik's cube in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I happened watched a demo in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4M_ZI_Pz874. I am curious about it . Is there any example about how to build it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16893/how-to-build-a-rubik%27s-cube-in-gazebo?/) by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The source code for that cube is here:

https://bitbucket.org/chapulina/chapulina_gazebo_models/src/default/puzzle_ball_joints/

The cube was modeled as boxes connected by ball joints to the center. In the past, I've also tried simulating the real mechanism, where the contacts between parts hold them together, but I never got it to be stable enough.

Have fun!

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longwoo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3628/longwoo/) on 2017-08-01**:
Thank you so much. I am trying to play it .